# iOS : FBAPIErrorDomain error 1

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I've got some problem with the login flow.
When a user click on login button he's redirect to the permissions flow.
If he accepts, there are two ways :

- no facebook app installed : everything is good, the user is redirected to my app
- facebook app installed : an error is returned.

[image]

As you can see, the app pic is empty, I don't know if it's a clue. I checked my bundle id, it's ok in ios side and facebook side.

I tried to login in different way, with FBLoginView, with

`[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allow LoginUI:completionHandler]`

but always the same error with the facebook app installed.

I really don't know where I failed.

Comment: Please don't put 'fixed' in the title. If you've solved your problem, post an answer, and then accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to be a pretty generic one.

You can try to change the sandbox flag to production on your Facebook app. (under the Facebook developer portal).